# gcp cloud datastore indexing strategy

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

New to datastore but familiar with Cassandra and Dynamo. I have a use case where I have an unique composite key made up of two fields (`A`, `B`). `B` would be in `desc` order. My access pattern would be to query for the latest (base on `B`) entities given an `A` value (with pagination). My problem is that `A` could have a very high cardinality (potentially in the 5-10 million range, but as low as 100-1000).

If this was in Dynamo I would have `A` be the partition key and `B` be the sort key.
In Datastore, however, the concept of key identifier is throwing me off. should I have unique CONCAT(A,B) be the key identifier (to achieve some sort of unique constraints)? And then add one index on `A` and `B` again for queries?

I can't find much information on the inner workings of Datastore so I'm not sure if having CONCAT(A,B) be the key identifier would distribute the data randomly. I'm guessing for fast queries I would want all entities with the same `A` value to be stored in the same partition. Or does index work like views in a relational database?

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_definition_and_structure) you may find the official documentation details regarding the structure of indexes and [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices) you may find the best practices to adapt for your use cases. I hope it helps.

Comment: Datastore allows you to filter on one property and sort on another. You could concat the two properties to create your UID or have Datastore auto generate one. Just make sure you have the appropriate indexes for A and B.